# Android build doesn't work from WSL

Tags: android, android-build, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My computer has a 240GB SSD and a 1TB HDD installed, and my SSD is nearly full though my HDD is only half full. I decided to go and try to build Android, so I opened the "Ubuntu 18.04" Windows Subsystem For Linux program and ran the commands according to the Android documentation. It downloaded all of the source code to my HDD just fine. However, when I tried to configure the project by running `lunch`, everything fell apart:

```
gjsman@DESKTOP:/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir$ lunch

Youre building on Linux

Lunch menu... pick a combo:
11:00:49 Could not create module-finder: finder encountered 18 errors: [/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/tools/tradefederation/core/prod-tests/src/com/android/app/tests: lstat
/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/tools/tradefederation/core/prod-tests/src/com/android/app/tests: no such file or directory
/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/tools/tradefederation/core/prod-tests/src/com/android/graphics/tests: lstat
/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/tools/tradefederation/core/prod-tests/src/com/android/graphics/tests: no such file or directory
/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/tools/tradefederation/core/prod-tests/src/com/android/security/tests: lstat
/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/tools/tradefederation/core/prod-tests/src/com/android/security/tests: no such file or directory
/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/tools/tradefederation/core/prod-tests/src/com/android/wireless/tests: lstat
/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/tools/tradefederation/core/prod-tests/src/com/android/wireless/tests: no such file or directory
/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/tools/tradefederation/core/prod-tests/src/com/android/framework/tests: lstat
/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/tools/tradefederation/core/prod-tests/src/com/android/framework/tests: no such file or directory
/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/prebuilts/gradle-plugin/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/0.13.0: lstat
/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/prebuilts/gradle-plugin/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/0.13.0: no such file or directory
/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/external/perfetto/src/ftrace_reader/test/data/android_hammerhead_MRA59G_3.4.0/events/vmscan/mm_vmscan_memcg_isolate: lstat
/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/external/perfetto/src/ftrace_reader/test/data/android_hammerhead_MRA59G_3.4.0/events/vmscan/mm_vmscan_memcg_isolate: no such file or directory
/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/external/perfetto/src/ftrace_reader/test/data/android_hammerhead_MRA59G_3.4.0/events/vmscan/mm_vmscan_memcg_reclaim_begin: lstat
/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/external/perfetto/src/ftrace_reader/test/data/android_hammerhead_MRA59G_3.4.0/events/vmscan/mm_vmscan_memcg_reclaim_begin: no such file or directory
/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/external/perfetto/src/ftrace_reader/test/data/android_hammerhead_MRA59G_3.4.0/events/vmscan/mm_vmscan_memcg_reclaim_end: lstat
/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/external/perfetto/src/ftrace_reader/test/data/android_hammerhead_MRA59G_3.4.0/events/vmscan/mm_vmscan_memcg_reclaim_end: no such file or directory
/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/external/perfetto/src/ftrace_reader/test/data/android_hammerhead_MRA59G_3.4.0/events/vmscan/mm_vmscan_memcg_softlimit_reclaim_begin: lstat
/mnt/e/GJSie/androidworkdir/external/perfetto/src/ftrace_reader/test/data/android_hammerhead_MRA59G_3.4.0/events/vmscan/mm_vmscan_memcg_softlimit_reclaim_begin: no such file or directory]...
```

Oddly, if I manually type in any of these folders, they **do exist**. I've tried `repo sync` repeatedly, and I can't figure out what is going wrong here.

Comment: WSL is an abstraction layer for linux. It works by translating windows api call to linux api call. It's still slow when working with filesystem, look at these issues: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2721 and https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/981. Don't use WSL if you're want to develop Android with Android Studio.

Comment: The first issue you mentioned (#2721) says Windows Defender Anti-Malware is slowing it down. @G.S. try turning that off and retrying, maybe? Please, let us know how it goes.